# Bootstrap column does not work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Brandi</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="col-md-3 well">Column 3</div>
<div class="col-md-3 well">Column 3</div>
<div class="col-md-3 well">Column 3</div>
<div class="col-md-3 well">Column 3</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

All links are working fine.But columns are not working.

Output:

[image]

Comment: can you open developer tools with F12 and see the network tab to see if its loading boostrat correctly?

Comment: Do you have any content in your `style.css`?  And I suggest you to add following meta tag in your header: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`.

Comment: add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` below `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: and do you have any `@media`- queries in your `style.css`? they can conflict with `bootstrap`'s @media-styles

Comment: it should work only with bootstrap.min.css included, with or without `container` class as ancestor - maybe that `.well` class have `width:100%` and overrides `md-3`

Comment: I have wrote nothing in my style.css file. I followed your advice, added viewport meta tag but nothing happened. @Igor Ivancha

Comment: in this case check, do you  have correct `bootstrap.min.css` file. change `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" media="all" />` to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: Here it is working on bootply: http://www.bootply.com/9tJjLJZ4IB . So i'm pretty sure either your links are broken or you added some css for this to happen.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, you need to have container, which will determine the sizes of the container depending on your screen size and preferably row which will determine the horizontal section in your container.

Here is a snippet from the bootstrap source code. It sets different sizes depending on the viewport/screen sizes

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

**Second**, you also need a meta tag to let the bootstrap know the screen sizes.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Here is the snippet. Try to see the result in the big and small screens.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title>Brandi</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3 well">Column 3</div>
     <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3 well">Column 3</div>
     <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3 well">Column 3</div>
     <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3 well">Column 3</div>                   
  </div>     
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The way grid works is, by dividing the grid number by 12. So when you have col-md-3 for example, the size of the div will be:

`3/12 * (container-size)`

Note that, the md is just determining on which screen it should apply. So, the choices are, `xs`, `sm`, `md`, `lg`

Answer (score 0):

it works perfectly for me when wrapping them inside an container class.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3 well">Column 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 well">Column 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 well">Column 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 well">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

Maybe your screen is to small for the md, try with xs, just to make sure its not because of screen size. (Sorry cant do comments yet)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-3 well">Column 3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 well">Column 3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 well">Column 3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 well">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: My screen size is 1365px in width. Why should it be small or extra small?

Comment: it should be just fine then, got anything at the style.css?

Answer (score 0):

You should load the `bootstrap.min.js` before anything else. (Except for jQuery of course, always load it first, but you get the point I am sure)

This also avoids any future problems which you are likely to encounter because you're loading your JavaScript on the bottom of your page. Move it to the header and before your CSS is being loaded.

It is also recommended to wrap your columns inside a `.row`, though it is not necessary. Otherwise your code seems to be all right!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine as it it is,May be It seems the path of 'js' and 'css' are wrong.
Try using

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Brandi</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-md-3 well">Column 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 well">Column 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 well">Column 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 well">Column 3</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my bootstrap.min.css file. It was not working properly though it was loading properly. When I changed the code and linked with a CDN then it worked. My code was

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

It was the main problem. Then I changed with...

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Now its OK. But I have a curiosity about this strange behavior of bootstrap.min.css file. Does it acts like this with other? If it does then what is the reason?

Comment: I'm guessing that the URL css/bootstrap.min.css was incorrect. Then Bootstrap would not work.